# How to get incoming sendgrid email on firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, http-post, sendgrid

I have a firebase function which I use as a webhook for sendgrid's inbound parse webhook. So that means whenever an email is sent to my domain, it calls the webhook. I know the webhook is being called, but I can't get to the data being sent by Sendgrid. [This link](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook/#example-raw-payload) states that all the information (text, sender, ect) should be right there in the headers. However when I print out `req.headers` I get this:

```
{ host: 'us-central1-project-name.cloudfunctions.net',
  'user-agent': 'Sendlib/1.0 server.sendgrid.net',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=xYzZY',
  forwarded: 'for="ip";proto=https',
  'function-execution-id': 'id',
  'x-appengine-city': '?',
  'x-appengine-citylatlong': '0.000000,0.000000',
  'x-appengine-country': 'US',
  'x-appengine-default-version-hostname': ~~~~~~~~~~~~~.appspot.com',
  'x-appengine-https': 'on',
  'x-appengine-region': '?',
  'x-appengine-request-log-id': 'super-long-id',
  'x-appengine-user-ip': 'ip',
  'x-cloud-trace-context': 'id/number;o=1',
  'x-forwarded-for': 'ip',
  'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  connection: 'close' }'
```

(Obviously I replaced all the ID's and everything)

Where is the email information? I have tried doing all of the following and none of them produced any information regarding the email.

```
exports.reciever = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  try {
   console.log("Email recieved");
   console.log(req);
   console.log(req.headers);
   console.log(req.header.to);
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.get('to'));
   console.log(req.body.to);
   console.log(req.rawBody);
   console.log(req.query);
   console.log(req.query.to);
   console.log(req.params);
   console.log(req.path);
   console.log(req.rawBody);
  } catch (e) {}
  finally {
      res.send("2xx");
  } 
})
```

Comment: The documentation says that the email information is in the body of the request, not the headers.  I'd expect the data you're looking for to be in req.body or req.rawBody.

Comment: the body object produces this wierd <Buffer> string followed by a series of characters busted into groups of 2. Do I need to decode this?

Comment: Yes, I would assume this node buffer contains the data in the post body as described by the documentation.  It's probably multipart data that needs special decoding.

Comment: Formidable produces an error when parsing it though. It says cannot read property 'content-length'  of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turns out it's actually very very simple. Add

```
.toString()
```

At the end of the `req.body` or `req.rawBody` object.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? When I do req.body.toString() I just get a long string it seems. How did you extract for example the subject and text? @A.S.H

Comment: This is where formidable or something else comes in. You still need to parse the stringified buffer after the `.toString()`. It is a tedious process to do alone, so I highly recommend a node library for parsing MIMEs

Comment: What lib did you use for this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is about to enable use in serverless environments (AWS Lambda, Firebase/Google Cloud Functions, etc.) and environments where the request has already been processed. Parse an email with MIME is not a good idea.
Thus, here my solution:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as express from 'express';
const formidable = require('formidable-serverless');

export class InboundEmail {
  constructor(from, subject, text, html, to) {}
  doStrategy() {
     //Store inbound email
     //Send outbound email
     //...
  }
}

export class EmailPostWebHook {
  private form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  private incomeEmail: IncomeEmail;

  async run(request: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    try {
      this.parse(request);
      await this.incomeEmail.doStrategy();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  }

  private parse(request: express.Request) {
    this.form.parse(request, (errors: any, fields: any) => {
      this.incomeEmail = new IncomeEmail(
        fields.from
        fields.subject,
        fiels.text
        fields.html,
        fields.to
      );
    });
  }
}


const app = express();

const emailPostWebHook = new EmailPostWebHook();
app.post('/', emailPostWebHook.run.bind(emailPostWebHook));

export const InboundEmailHook = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 30,
    memory: '2GB',
  })
  .https.onRequest(app);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.15.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.7.0",
    "formidable-serverless": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@firebase/firestore-types": "^1.11.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "tslint": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

References:

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/docs/examples/webhooks-docker/routes/inbound-parse.js

https://github.com/Amit-A/formidable-serverless/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable

Comment: You helped me a lot!  This worked for me. The important key is to use 'formidable-serverless'. Many thanks.

Comment: I getting the error message "Unexpected token class"

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it working by installing Busboy in the functions-directory and then using the code provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54026200/10372124